# Set month on Kendo Angular Calendar

Tags: javascript, angularjs, kendo-ui

I've got a dropdown with months, and I've got a Kendo calendar using AngularJS. When the user selects a month from the dropdown, I need the calendar to display that month, *without* changing the actual selected date. Does anybody know how to do this?

Thanks!

Comment: You can use calendar api to set necessary date after month changes.

Comment: @dfsq example please?

Comment: A bit more context might be useful here. It's a wonder what you need this functionality for exactly...